# "The front door slid open" grammar explanation

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech

> The front door slid open.

I am curious about "slid open" in this context. Is "slid" a verb or an adverb? Is "open" a verb or not?

Is a "slide open" a phrasal verb like "push open"?

Comment: Slid is the past tense of _slide_. Open is an adverb meaning that the door did not move into a closed state.

Comment: @oerkelens If "open" is adverb then what is a question for this adverb "how?", "in what manner?" or something else?

Comment: "Into what position/direction?" What question do you use for _on_ in "I turned the light on" or for _out_ in "I kicked the dog out"?

Comment: @oerkelens I kicked the dog (where?) out
"I turned the light on" I can't ask a question for the word "on" in this sentence

Comment: You could call it an adjective, a resultative secondary predicate, like in "I knocked him **unconscious**" (not *\*unconsciously*).

Comment: You kicked the dog _to where_. The answer to "where?" would be "outside", or "between the legs". But I don't think it is very useful to get obsessed with finding the questions, if the answers are clear and the meaning is clear :)

Comment: Maybe "slide open" is a phrasal verb like "push open"? That's why "open" hasn't changed its form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a phrasal verb. In phrasal verbs, the the two words together take on an entirely new meaning. For example, when I say:

> Why don't you grow up?

I don't mean, "Why don't you *grow taller*?"; I mean, "Why don't you *act more mature*?"

However, when I say:

> Would you please slide the door open.

I mean exactly what the two words mean: *open* the door, by *sliding* it.

---

The next part of your question is interesting. My first thought was that *slide* is the verb and *open* is an adverb:

- Please slide the door open.
- Please slide the door closed.
- Please slide the door to let some fresh air in.

But that last one seems a bit peculiar. It seems like I am trying to say:

- Please open the door to let some fresh air in.

Which made me wonder if *open* is the verb and *slide* is the adverb.

---

Back to your sentence:

> The front door slid open.

I think *slid* is the verb in that sentence. Why? Because that's the word I would change when I'm changing the tense of the sentence:

- The front door slid open.
- The front door is sliding open.
- The front door will slide open.

The word *open* functions as an adverb – we can confirm this by replacing *open* with other adverbs:

- The front door slid noisily.
- The front door is sliding roughly.
- The front door will slide tomorrow.

Comment: "open" as adverb confuses me because doesn't change its form.

Comment: Plenty of adverbs don't change their form, like "tomorrow" or "even".