# What function does 'open' have in 'She pushed open the door'?

Tags: word-order, syntax

I find this sentence in number 12 out of 4.1 exercise in a book named *Advanced GRAMMAR IN USE* published by Cambridge university press.

> She pushed open the door and ran into the room.

I looked up the dictionary and think that the word 'open' must be an adjective. But I don't understand why the word 'open' is put in that place instead of putting it between the word 'the' and the word 'door'.

The pattern 'push sth + adj. ' is found in *Oxford English dictionary for advanced learners* and there is an example sentence: *I pushed the door open.* So can I think that 'open' in this sentence is an adjective?

Besides, almost any dictionaries do **not** consider 'open' as an adverb including non-ESL dictionaries such as *webster's new world college dictionary* and *merriam webster's collegiate dictionary*, which suprises me a lot !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The front door slid open" grammar explanation](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/the-front-door-slid-open-grammar-explanation)

Comment: In my opinion, this is **not** a duplicate of ["The front door slid open" grammar explanation – FumbleFingers](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/the-front-door-slid-open-grammar-explanation).

Comment: Please explain why you think the syntactic breakdown of ***slide open*** should be any different to that of ***push open***. @You might also consider, for example, [“scraped open a grave” Why two successive verbs?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78790/) (and doubtless many others) which I think covers exactly the same issue.

Comment: The reason why I think that way is explained in the main question description block.

Comment: From one of the answers to one of the earlier questions, [So you could say that "open" is the new state, and thus an **adjective**, or that it's the direction or manner in which it was scraped, and is thus an **adverb**.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/78812/126) These "part of speech" category names are a broad brush that aren't always useful in every context.

Comment: *"The pattern 'push sth + adj. ' is found in Oxford English dictionary for advanced learners and there is an example sentence: I pushed the door open. So can I think that 'open' in this sentence is an adjective?"* -- Yes. My general advice is the sooner you separate the part of speech from the function, the less confused you will be. E.g., if you confused what it is with what it does, you might think, because *Safety* in *Safety is important* is a noun, a *to*-infinitive can be a noun(!) too, like in *To err is human*. (And, really, some books will tell you so. No wonder it's confusing!)

Answer (score 3):

The writer maybe sees **push open** as a phrasal verb, like **put on**. Phrasal verbs can be used in two ways:

> 1) She **put** the dress **on**
>  
>   2) She **put on** the dress.

Your sentence matches form 2). I cannot find any dictionary evidence to confirm that it is normal to use **push open** as a phrasal verb, but this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=push%20open&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpush%20open%3B%2Cc0) indicates that quite a few writers use this form.

Here are a couple of examples:

> When you've finished putting beads on all the pins, open the big (#3) safety pin and use the nail file to push open the little loop-the-loop at the end of it [My best friends and me](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=H6KccG7upNsC&q=%22push%20open%22&dq=%22push%20open%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK7szY7LbOAhWEqxoKHfuSBeYQ6AEIRDAI)
>
> Silence promises danger not peace, for always the sounds that push open my door or your door, are remembered as coming out of nothing. [In the shadow of sharpeville](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=hOCi9hVGBBYC&pg=PA206&dq=%22push%20open%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK7szY7LbOAhWEqxoKHfuSBeYQ6AEIODAG#v=onepage&q=%22push%20open%22&f=false)

Comment: If **push open** is a phrasal verb, then can I consider 'open' as an adjective here?

Comment: @MingLu, Phrasal verbs are normally made up of a verb and a particle (usually an adverb or preposition).  The link provided by FumbleFingers suggests that **open** can indeed be an adverb, although this does not appear in dictionaries. I would be inclined to regard it as an adverb in your sentence.

Comment: The pattern 'push sth + adj. ' is found in _Oxford English dictionary for advanced learners_ and there is an example sentence: _I pushed the door open_. So can I think that 'open' in the phrasal verb 'push open' is an adjective?

Comment: @MingLu, Your sentence is not a good or typical example of usage. If you choose to think of **push open** as a phrasal verb, you are free to do so. If you choose to thing of **open** as an adjective within this phrasal verb, you are free to do so. However, I would not recommend this: I would recommend sticking to the construction documented in OEDAL, namely "push sth + adj".

Comment: @JavaLatte Do you think "Push it open" is similar to "Knock him dead" in which dead is an adjective, or so I think?

Comment: @learner, They are not similar at all; as far as I know, "knock dead" is only used in the theatrical expression "knock 'em dead" http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/knock-em-dead. "knock over" and knock out" are similar, and both are flexible about where you put the over/out. "He knocked over the vase" or "he knocked the vase over". According to OED, over can be a preposition or an adverb., but not an adjective. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/over

Answer (score 2):

Adjectives answer the question "which?" or "what kind?".

*Adverbs* answer the question "how?"

Verbs that change or set the state of something can be followed by a word that describes what that state is.  This word answers the question "how?", so I believe it's an adverb, not an adjective.

Many adverbs can be put in multiple places in sentences without change in meaning.  You can say "She pushed the door open" and it would mean the same.

> But I don't understand why the word 'open' is put in that place instead of putting it between the word 'the' and the word 'door

If you  say "She pushed the open door", then *open* is an adjective modifying *door*.  This is a common pattern in English - {article/determiner} {adjective} {adjective} ... {noun}.

Since it's an adjective, it's answering the question "which" or "what kind" of door.  So this would mean the door was already open when she pushed it.

Comment: But I could not find the word 'open' as an adverb in _Oxford English dictionary for advanced learners_ !!!

Comment: I think @JavaLatte's theory of it being treated as a phrasal verb might be explain it better.  You can separate the second word of phrasal verbs in a similar manner.  I *think* the second word in phrasal verbs can be considered an adverb.  In any event it's definitely not an adjective.

Comment: @Ming Lu: Consider *She painted the door blue*. You won't find ***blue*** defined as an adverb in any dictionaries either.

Comment: The pattern 'push sth + adj. ' is found in _Oxford English dictionary for advanced learners_ and there is an example sentence: _I pushed the door open._ So I belive 'open' in the phrasal verb 'push open' is an adjective.

Comment: @LawrenceC Can u explain it?

Comment: Not really, maybe the above commentors are right.  You still can't say *I pushed the open door* to mean you opened the door, though.