# Why, in one simple sentence, there are two verbs?

Tags: verbs, syntax, parts-of-speech

Jerry **kicked** the **door** open.

1st verb-kick
2nd verb-open

Why there are two verbs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The front door slid open" grammar explanation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21050/the-front-door-slid-open-grammar-explanation)

Comment: @ColleenV: I initially copied your vtc, but after comparing the answers there and here I've retracted it. Shame about the downvote for the *question* - I'm sure it's a confusing area for many learners - I suspect particularly so for speakers of non Franco-Germanic languages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree this is confusing for learners… and probably some native speakers too if you asked them to parse the sentence grammatically. I know we have a good duplicate target for this one, I just couldn’t find it. I can understand why someone downvoted it… the question doesn’t demonstrate much effort. I don’t know how a learner would search for an answer though. I know the answer and can’t find it lol.

Comment: This may be a better duplicate target: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/78790/9161

Comment: @ColleenV: I think that's a *much* better dup! Well - it's got good answers, anyway. But because I've already vtc'd and retracted, I can't vtc again. Darth's answer here is also good, though, and I think it's a shame the system doesn't automatically allow for links on the surviving Question to at least good *Answers* posted against other questions subsequently closed in favour of that survivor.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As long as the closed question has a positive score it will be linked to others improving its chances of being found. tagging it properly helps too.

Comment: @ColleenV: Shows how much notice I take of the tireless efforts of the backroom elves working on SO  user interface! I knew there were auto-generated *"**Related**"* questions on the right-hand sidebar of a Question page, but I hadn't consciously recognised that *"**Linked**"* was sometimes there as well, with closed duplicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, *open* isn't a verb, it's an adjective. "The door is open" is like "the door is green", it's describing the *state* of the door, not an action.

"Jerry kicked the door open" is like "Jerry painted the door green". The adjective is the new state and the verb is how it got there.

Comment: "Opened " vs"Open" How both can be adjective? "Green" might be adjective &complete the meaning of the verb "painted", but how a action word (open) can be used as complement.

Comment: "Jerry kicked the door into an open position." (We wouldn't say that, but _open_ describes the state of the door after the kick.)

Comment: @Sam As a native english speaker, I would *never* say "Jerry kicked the door opened".  That's not grammatical. I can't think of any context where "opened" would be an adjective; it's always a past-tense verb. If you're describing the state of a thing, the word is "open". (Note that the opposite of the adjective "open" is "closed" so that's probably fairly confusing, but that's how it is.)

Comment: All the following are correct: "Please open the door"; "Jerry opened the door"; "The door is open".  "Please close the door"; "Jerry closed the door"; "The door is closed".  Sorry about that. English is weird.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym the newly **opened** road. Here opened is used in the sense(made open or clear).

Comment: No, "newly-opened" is using "opened" as a verb.  Consider a "freshly-painted door"

Comment: @DarthPseudonym the **opened(not sealed or having been unsealed)** package lay on the table.(Here also it's an adjective).

Comment: Okay, that's fair, but you could also talk about an *open* box on the table, which would be the more common way to do that.